# ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘it’ with no type for auto iterator?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iterator, auto

I have these six lines:

```
    auto it = rcp_amxinfo.find(LocalPass.script);//175
    if (it != rcp_amxinfo.end()) //176
    {//177
        if(it->second.GPSRouteCalculated.PublicFound)//178
        {
            ...
            amx_Exec(LocalPass.script, NULL, it->second.GPSRouteCalculated.POINTER);//186
```

they compile perfectly fine in VS2012, but in GCC on centOS6 I get these errors:

```
./RouteConnector/main.cpp:175: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘it’ with no type
./RouteConnector/main.cpp:175: error: cannot convert ‘std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<AMX* const, Callbacks> >’ to ‘int’ in initialization
./RouteConnector/main.cpp:176: error: no match for ‘operator!=’ in ‘it != rcp_amxinfo.std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::end [with _Key = AMX*, _Tp = Callbacks, _Compare = std::less<AMX*>, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<AMX* const, Callbacks> >]()’
./RouteConnector/main.cpp:178: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
./RouteConnector/main.cpp:186: error: base operand of ‘->’ is not a pointer
```

rcp_amxinfo is defined as follow:

```
struct CallbackAMX
{
    bool PublicFound;
    int POINTER;
    CallbackAMX()
    {
        PublicFound = false;
        POINTER = 0;
    }
};

struct Callbacks
{
    CallbackAMX ClosestNodeIDChange;
    CallbackAMX GPSRouteCalculated;
};

std::map            <AMX*, Callbacks>               rcp_amxinfo;
```

How can I solv these errors on linux?

Comment: `auto` only deduces the type in C++11. It is the default storage type in C++03, as opposed to `register` and such.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Enable C++11 mode when building. You do that by adding `-std=gnu++11` (to also get GCC extensions, which are on by default), or `-std=c++11` (for only ISO C++) to your compiler flags.

`auto` means something different in C++11 (where it deduces the type) than it does in the previous standard (where it specifies automatic storage class.)

Comment: I believe the flag is `-std=gnu++11`